# SetEnv variable in .htaccess in magento

Tags: magento-1.8, .htaccess

In .htaccess file in magento if SetEnv variable is set how this is processed in magento.
For example:

```
SetEnv MAGE_RUN_CODE store
```

How does this works in magento index.php and displays the corresponding store.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting environment variables in the .htaccess or virtualhost means they become available in PHP's $_SERVER superglobal array.

This bit of code in the index.php file grabs the store codes from $_SERVER and passes them to Mage::run when bootstrapping Magento.

```
/* Store or website code */
$mageRunCode = isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE']) ? $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE'] : '';

/* Run store or run website */
$mageRunType = isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE']) ? $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE'] : 'store';

Mage::run($mageRunCode, $mageRunType);
```

Mage::run sets up an instance of Mage_Core_Model_App and passes the codes to it, and Mage_Core_Model_App is responsible for everything from there, including rendering the particular store you've chosen.